# What's a frost-gley?

Tags: paleoclimatology, soil, ice-age, soil-moisture, permafrost

I've noticed this term in a book about Pleistocene East Europe. It's apparently a soil which was formed during the interstadials, but that's all my book says, and I can't find much more on the internet. So what more can be said about frost-gley, preferably with sources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A frost-gley is a waterlogged permafrost soil. IOW, a [gleysol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleysol) that has undergone [cryoturbation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryoturbation).